# Why is presentModalViewController not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am presenting a modalcontroller in a view, after i dissmiss the view i want to present another modalView but the code is not working, i have a delegate method that is being called when i press a button on the first modal vieview in witch i have the code.

inside the parentView the method for the firstview delegat:

```
    -(void)newMessageModalView:(NewMessageModalView *)controller didFinishSelecting:(int)selectedChannel{
                [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
           SecondView * detailView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
                [self presentModalViewController:SecondView animated:YES];
                [detailView release]; 
                [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are presenting SecondView, which is your class and not your instance. Even if that was right, you are dismissing it straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Move [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; to detailView.m

```
-(void)newMessageModalView:(NewMessageModalView *)controller didFinishSelecting:(int)selectedChannel{
    SecondView * detailView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:SecondView animated:YES];
    [detailView release]; 
}
```

For example, in detailView.m

```
- (void)cancelBtnTouched:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```